# Create a set from a list using `set` vs. unpacking into curly brackets

Tags: python, list, set, unpack

In Python, a `set` can be created from a `list` using either the `set` constructor or by unpacking the list into curly brackets. For example:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_set = set(my_list)
```

or

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_set = {*my_list}
```

Are there any specific reasons or use cases where one approach is preferred over the other? What are the advantages or disadvantages of each method in terms of performance, readability, or any other relevant factors?

Comment: These are same, choose as your convenience

Comment: Just different ways of doing the same thing. Usually you would only see the unpacking form when it was needed to include more elements, e.g. `{*my_list, 4}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle difference.

`set(my_list)` produces whatever the callable bound to `set` returns. `set` is a built-in name for the set type, but it's possible to shadow the name with a global or local variable.

`{*my_list}`, on the other hand, *always* creates a new `set` instance. It's not possible to change what the brace syntax means without modifying the Python implementation itself (and then, you are no longer implementing Python, but a very Python-like language).

In CPython, using `{*mylist}` also avoids a function call, it uses `BUILD_SET` and `SET_UPDATE` opcodes rather than calling whatever `set` is bound to.